# CSS dynamically change clickable area on hover to resize if mouse on lower half of div

Tags: css

I have a div set to absolute which expands on hover by changing to position:static to display the full text inside.

I'm wondering if it's possible to make this shrink if the user is outside the original bounds rather than the new enlarged box.

```
.box {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box:hover {
  position:static;
}
```

This works but is a bit annoying as it fills a chunk of the screen and user has to move the mouse outside the div for it to shrink back, I'd like them to move the mouse outside the original size of the div rather than the overflowing div to shrink it back.

Any tricks to maintain the clickable area to the original boundaries when showing the expanded div?

Comment: Any template you tried will be really useful?

Comment: that's the code, i'm just putting a large amount of text in the box and hiding the rest with the overflow so it shows the full text on hover, I would like it to shrink back based on the overflow rather than hovering outside the resized box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added this style (`background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);`) just to show the original container, it should be changed to  `background-color: transparent;` for actual code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 2s;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 2s;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}

.box:hover+.box2 {
  position: static;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this works thanks! What does the "hover+" do? I can't specify fixed height for the container so I'll have to see if it works in real life.

Comment: Selects the immediate next sibling of the selector i.e. .box div's immediate  next element .box2

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try.

Comment: Be aware though that this will make any content of .box2 that is covered by .box unavailable for user interaction.

Comment: The div just contains static text so that should be okay, thanks!!

Comment: I have to put the absolute div inside the container to fill it as I can't use fixed heights. So I need to shrink the boxes based on the child so I can't use the + selector for this.

Comment: It's not possible to select a parent div using css so I used your trick and put it before and resized the absolute div using javascript to match the other div. Thanks.